# Getting Bound Statement from Snowflake SQL Connection

Tags: node.js, parameters, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find a way to get the sql statements with the bound parameters to print.

I have a snowflake connector object that is similar to this:

```
snowflake.execute({
    sqlText: 'SELECT * FROM TBL_A WHERE A B ?',
    binds: [12],
    fetchAsString: ['NUMBER'],
    complete: function (err, stmt, rows) {
      if (err) {
          console.error('Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ' + stmt.getSqlText())
      }
      else {
        // Do some stuff
      }
    }
  })
```

When it errors out, I want it to show me the actual SQL text being executed:

```
'SELECT * FROM TBL_A WHERE A B 12'
```

However, the only thing I can get it to print is the sql with the parameter holder.

Comment: There are some examples given here
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#executing-statements

Comment: Thanks @AbhiReddy. I read the documentation, and I have used the err.message, but it nothing I have found prints the query as it is being executed, with the parameters filled in.